# Hide Console.ReadLine input from console after submitting - C# Console App

Tags: c#, .net, input, output, console-application

In a simple console app that requests the users input, I'm asking for a user input. That input is then saved into a variable for later use.

How can I display the input while it's being typed into the console, but hide it after its been submitted?

For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        string input = null;

        Console.WriteLine("Type Something: ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("You Typed" + input);
    }
}
```

After running the above code, the output below is printed to the console is:

```
Type Something:
abc 123 
You Typedabc 123
```

How can I adapt this code so as, after the user has typed and submitted the input, it does not appear in the output?

Comment: Remove the line `Console.WriteLine("You Typed" + input);`

Comment: @mattshu, thats exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this before by creating a method that moves the cursor to the previous lines, writes whitespace over the line, and resets the cursor to the beginning of the line again:

```
private static void DeletePrevConsoleLine()
{
    if (Console.CursorTop == 0) return;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
}
```

Usage:

```
string input = null;

Console.WriteLine("Type Something: ");
input = Console.ReadLine();
DeletePrevConsoleLine();
Console.WriteLine("You Typed: " + input);

Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```